# Create several folders in a directory with a loop to write the names R

Tags: r, path, directory

I am trying to create several subfolder in a parent folder. I created this code but it does not create my subfolders. I would like to create subfolders in the folder "xxxx".

```
setwd<- "path/xxxx"
subfolder_names<- (a, b, c, d) 
for (j in1: length(subfolder_names)){
folder<-dir.create("path/xxxx/", paste(j))}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

Some notes:

- Use c() to combine elements into a list and add quotations (") around the strings to make sure R sees them as data and not variables.
- Make sure that "in" and "1:" in the for loop statement are separated by a space and "1:" and "length()" are adjacent to one another.
- In the for loop, paste0 can be used to concatenate two strings. Here we concatenate both the directory and the subfolder name from the subfolder_names list we created.

```html
subfolder_names <- c("a","b","c","d") 
for (j in 1:length(subfolder_names)){
  folder<-dir.create(paste0("path/xxxx/",subfolder_names[j]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments!  However, I might not made good explanations of my issue. I would like to create the new folders in the folder "xxxx" with only the name "a", "b", "c", and "d". Here, I created folders that are in the same directory than my folder "xxxx".

Comment: The code above, assuming "path/xxxx/" is correctly given as a full file path, would produce four folders:
- "path/xxxx/a/"
- "path/xxxx/b/"
- "path/xxxx/c/"
- "path/xxxx/d/"

All folders are the children of folder "path/xxxx/" and are not in the same directory as folder "path/xxxx/" - If this is not what is desired, please explain.

Comment: Thank you, I understood my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment above, I have this and it works.

```
subfolder_names <- c("a","b","c","d") 

for (j in seq_along(subfolder_names)){
  folder<-dir.create(paste0("C:/Users/OGUNDEPO EZEKIEL .A/Desktop/",subfolder_names[j]))}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
base_path <- "path/xxxx"
subfolder_names <- ("a", "b", "c", "d") 

for (name in subfolder_names) {

 path <- paste0(base_path, "/", name)
 dir.create(path)

}
```

Comment: This could be the solution that solves the problem, but please add some information on how and what all help in solving the problem, so that future readers take the most out of your answer.

Comment: I don't think this needs any explanation. The variable names are self explanatory, especially in the context of having this question. It is 5 lines total.